# Removing specific view controller from UINavigation stack not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

The requirement is fairly simple, heres some code:

```
- (void)returnToDetailsScreen {
    UINavigationController *mainNavController = self.navigationController;
    NSArray *reversedViewControllers =  [[mainNavController.viewControllers reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
    for (UIViewController *viewController in reversedViewControllers) {

       if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[DetailsViewController class]]) {
            [mainNavController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
            return;
       }

       if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ChoosePathViewController class]]) {
            NSMutableArray *amendedViewControllerStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[mainNavController viewControllers]];
            [amendedViewControllerStack removeObject:viewController];
            [mainNavController setViewControllers:amendedViewControllerStack];
        }
    }
}
```

In short all I want to do is two things, when iterating over the viewControllers I want to either, when I find the `DetailsViewController` pop to the screen and if I find the `ChoosePathViewController` I want to remove it from the list of viewControllers. However, the `amendedViewControllerStack` removes `ChoosePathViewController` but the `[mainNavController setViewControllers:amendedViewControllerStack];` never actually updates the `navigationController` viewControllers.

I've checked on several SO posts and this code shouldn't be giving any issues. Any ideas as to why its not working?

Comment: In short yes, the stack usually looks something like this: HomeController, DetailsViewController, ChoosePathViewController, VerificationController. I want to pop to the DetailsViewController. However, when so doing, I see the ChoosePathViewController for a few seconds and I dont want this. Hence, why I'm trying to remove it from the list

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment before you wrote, I thought I misunderstood you but it seems I understood you. However, I have not tried this line of code ever, but have you read the documentations regarding this, if you have your? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers?language=objc , I am not sure if "setViewControllers" work the same as "setViewControllers:animated", have you tried it? If it solves your problem let me know I will update the answer.

Comment: @Sneak The docs explain that setViewControllers is equivalent to calling setViewControllers:animated: with the animated parameter set to NO. Remember that with objc foo.viewControllers = bar; can be written as [foo setViewControllers:bar];

Comment: @Bamsworld I deleted my comment since I digged into the property documentation and it is indeed called with animations:NO as you said! Will give you an upvote for that! However, that only means that Apple implemented a custom method that calls the equivalent as animation:NO as they documented, it does not mean that foo.setViewControllers = bar is the same as [foo setViewControllers:animated:] in objective-c , unless you have a custom setter that calls the animation block as NO inside anyways as they apparantly do.

Comment: @Sneak Yeah thanks was just shedding some light on the question in your comment. You make a valid point, however I see similar design patterns throughout their apis. At a guess I reckon the property setter would call the animated method under the hood but it's just a guess.

Comment: @Bamsworld Yeah you are correct, I guess they would have some form of optimization that makes it run under the hood as you say, that would be logical with Apple! :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have no break in: `if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[ChoosePathViewController class]]) {` to break out of the loop.

Could it be that you are setting the array to the navigationController and at the same time you pop to **DetailsViewController** and that would make the animation wierd somehow?

EDIT:
One suggestion, why not create a NSMutableArray and add the viewControllers you actually want in the tree, in the order you want it,  while iterating, and after you are finished , you just run the "setViewControllers" method with your new updated array of VC?